# Unable to get ECSOperator (Fargate) to work with Airflow

Tags: airflow, aws-fargate

I'm getting this error when using ECSOperator to run tasks via ECS Fargate in Airflow 1.10.1. DAG code available [here](https://pastecode.xyz/view/raw/4cccdebb)

```
[2019-04-15 15:57:36,960] {{models.py:1788}} ERROR - An error occurred 
(InvalidParameterException) when calling the RunTask operation: Network 
Configuration must be provided when networkMode 'awsvpc' is specified.
```

Not sure what is wrong there, as `network_configuration` is passed in the args dictionary, similar to what is done here https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/tests/contrib/operators/test_ecs_operator.py#L61

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*network_configuration* has been added to ESCOperator since *Airflow v1.10.3*. I would suggest upgrading the Airflow version to *v1.10.3*.

Reference:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/airflow/contrib/operators/ecs_operator.py#L69

Answer (score 2):

Sample configuration of ECSOperator to run Fargate on
Airflow version - v1.10.3

```
def get_ecs_operator_args(param):
    return dict(

launch_type="FARGATE", 
              # The name of your task as defined in ECS

task_definition="my_automation_task",
              # The name of your ECS cluster

cluster="my-cluster", 
              network_configuration={

                    'awsvpcConfiguration': {
                           'securityGroups': ['sg-hijk', 'sg-abcd'],
                           'subnets': ['subnet-lmn'],
                           'assignPublicIp': "ENABLED"
                       }
               }, 
              overrides = {
                        'containerOverrides': [
                          {
                               'name': "my-container",
                               'command': ["python", "myCode.py",
                                           str(param)]
                           }
                         ]
                },


region_name="us-east-1")

ecs_args = get_ecs_operator_args("{{ dag_run.conf['name'] }}")

my_operator = ECSOperator( task_id= "task_0",**ecs_args, dag=dag)
```